# IE7 CSS Broken to a Mystifying Degree

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I had this page working in IE7, but then I made some changes (small additions that I want to keep), and the whole thing went up in flames.

There are two big issues.  The main one relates to the element, div#filters.  I had this working previously through some IE7 hacks but now it's a giant mess.

The other issue is the google map, which is initiated within div#map.

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kv3JV/

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Went up in flames? That must have been exciting.

Comment: Maybe a slight exaggeration, but have you seen it? One day, it's working, the next, nothing shows up on the page.  When you start fiddling around with individual components, you can see that the positioning is bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

In search.css, remove the following declarations from the `span.loc.header` selector:

```
position:relative;
top:-1px;
```

and the following declarations from the `div#amenities label` selector:

```
position:relative;
top:-2px;
```

I don't know what these declarations were trying to accomplish, nor why they would mess up IE7 so badly, but when I removed them from a local copy of search.css, they made the listings and the map reappear, and I don't notice a difference in the display of the location headers or amenity labels.

Comment: I just saw this answer Max and it made me really excited to try it out.  Unfortunately, I now have a massive IE7 memory leak problem. I literally can't open the developers toolbar.  IE7!!!!!! As soon as I figure out how to look at this, I will.  Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Hey Max, your suggestion greatly, greatly improved things.  I still have one big issue.  The Google Map isn't showing for some reason.  I can't figure that out.